# How to add all the rows of a column into a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine I had an "id" column and each of its rows contained a number. Lets say I have 3 rows at the moment. row 1 contains 1111, row 2 contains 2222, row 3 contains 3333.

I want to get the row values into a variable, and separate each row's data by a comma. The final result I expect is $variable = 1111,2222,3333.

I got this far code-wise:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("streamlist") or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT web_id FROM streams") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

            $streamlist = $row['web_id'].",";

            echo $streamlist;

        }

?>
```

The problem is that I then need each row's information singularly:

```
<?php

    $numbers = explode(',', $streamlist);
    $firstpart = $numbers[0];

    echo $firstpart;

?>
```

And the above code doesn't work inside the while() statement, nor does this:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("streamlist") or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT web_id FROM streams") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

            $streamlist = $row['web_id'].",";

        }

    $numbers = explode(',', $streamlist);
    $firstpart = $numbers[0];

    echo $firstpart;

?>
```

So basically, how can I get all of the information of the rows into a variable, and make them seperated by commas, in order to then get each number singularly?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php   or if you insist on retrieving a CSV value from MySQL, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: What else are you doing with the data in the comma-separated format?  Why not just build an array with your data and skip the comma-separation altogether?

Comment: @Crontab I must then use the id's retrieved from each row to verify if the online-streams are online or offline, in order to decide wether or not they should be displayed on the website's front-page. This is the main reason why I'm trying to avoid lots of queries (i could easily get the id's by using "SELECT web_id FROM streams WHERE  id = 1" and so on).

Comment: Use one query to validate whether it's online or not. Do you have some flag in the database that gives the state of offline or online? Just adjust your query like: `SELECT web_id FROM streams WHERE online='1'` or however it's designed.

Comment: @Blake I thoud about that but I would need to have some kind of cron job constantly updating the rows, reason why I discarded that possibility.

Comment: why don't you use array?

Comment: @user1298923 Why not when the user activates their stream, it changes their flag to online? When they de-activate, it updates again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("streamlist") or die(mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT web_id FROM streams") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    $streamlist[] = $row['web_id'];

}

foreach ($streamlist as $row) {

    // Do whatever you want with the data
    echo $row.',';

}

$comma_separated = implode(",", $streamlist);
```

Comment: Hello, I managed to figure out what I needed by applying the "$streamlist[] = $row['web_id'];" part of your code. It turns out it's alot more simple than I thoud and I don't need to go through the separating proccess since I can just use $streamlist[row_number] to get the information from specific row's. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The $streamlist scope doesn't seem right. Try:

```
$streamlist = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

        $streamlist .= $row['web_id'].",";

    }
```

Comment: Just see something in you loop: `$streamlist .= $row['web_id'].",";` i think you forgot the concat operator. Edited my post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, try this on for size:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("streamlist") or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT web_id, nextrow, nextrow2 FROM streams") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)){
        // $array_data will contain the array with all columns from the query (usable for your individual data needs as well)
        $array_data[] = $row;
        $var_string .= implode(",",$row);
        // $var_string will contain your giant blob comma separated string    
    }   
echo "<pre>"; print_r($array_data);echo "</pre>";
echo $var_string;
// These are for outputting the results
?>
```

Comment: Hello, when I try to echo $var_string to see what it contains, it only retrieves "18755", which is the first row's value of web_id.

Comment: Okay, let me re-state your needs to make sure I understand them. You want to pull your entire query set into one comma separated string?

Comment: For example, by using while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { echo $row['web_id'].","; } after my query, I can echo every single table in the column web_id, which are all numbers. What I wanted to do here is to insert all of the row's information into a variable. For example, if the first row of the web_id column contained 1111 and the second row of the web_id column contained 2222, I would want $var to retrieve 1111,2222. Thanks for helping.

Comment: See updated code for what I think is more accurate to your question.

Comment: Your code works perfectly if I delete the line with "echo "<pre>"; print_r($array_data);echo "</pre>";". However, I cannot select which id i want to work with. In my example code, if I echo $firstpart($firstpart = $numbers[0];), I get the first row's information, which in this case would be 1111. Any way to make it so  I can do this?

Comment: I managed to figure everything out with everyone's help. I have to specially thank you for all the time you dedicated to helping me. Thanks :)

Comment: If an answer was provided, please mark it as the answer. Glad I could help.